# Button did not trigger JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a button, then the button is supposed to triggered a JS function that will call another JS function. I tried to put Alert function in JS to test if it triggered, but it didn't. Anyone can help me?

Why it didn't get triggered?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnProcess3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  alert("hi")
  jsProcess(0);

  $("#btnProcess3").click(function() {
    alert("hi")
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    jsProcess(1);
  });
});

function jsProcess(action) {
  var page;
  var sDate;
  var sBizDate;
  sDate = $('#txtDate').val();

  if ($('#chkuseBizDate').is(':checked')) {
    sBizDate = $('#txtBizDate').val();
  } else {
    sBizDate = sDate;
  }
  page = "LoadPPSFile_details01.asp?TaskId=<%=sTaskId %>&txtDate=" + (sDate) + "&RunProcess=" + action + "&txtBizDate=" + (sBizDate);
  document.getElementById("IProcess").src = page;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="btnProcess" id="btnProcess3" value="Start - Services" width="250" style="VISIBILITY:show; WIDTH: 150px; HEIGHT: 22px; Background-Color:#1E90FF; Border-Color:white; Color:white; Font-Weight:bold;Font-family:Verdana;Cursor:hand; "
/>
```

Comment: As this seemingly has nothing to do with C#, VB or VBA I've edited the question to remove reference to them

Comment: Also, it looks like you have some server-side code in your JS. Ensure you're running this JS code in a location where this will be interpreted correctly, ie. ***NOT*** in a .js file

Comment: That because you on document ready disable that button by  `$("#btnProcess3").attr("disabled", "disabled");` . So remove this line then retry!!

Comment: How do you click a disabled button? A disabled button is not going to register a click event.

Comment: but i have a button that used the same structure of code. Attribute Visibility:Show in the HTML code should enable the JS right? I copy the same structure from other code in my project, that's why i confused with this one.

Also, i have tried to change the JS to :
            $("#btnProcess3").attr("disabled", false);

but it still didn't triggered the JS :/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing some code that the `jsProcess()` is looking for, but the Button performs as excepted, when you remove the Disabling part.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $("#btnProcess3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  // alert("hi")
  // jsProcess(0);

  $("#btnProcess3").click(function() {
    alert("I'm triggered!")
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    // jsProcess(1);
  });
});

function jsProcess(action) {
  var page;
  var sDate;
  var sBizDate;
  sDate = $('#txtDate').val();

  if ($('#chkuseBizDate').is(':checked')) {
    sBizDate = $('#txtBizDate').val();
  } else {
    sBizDate = sDate;
  }
  page = "LoadPPSFile_details01.asp?TaskId=<%=sTaskId %>&txtDate=" + (sDate) + "&RunProcess=" + action + "&txtBizDate=" + (sBizDate);
  document.getElementById("IProcess").src = page;
}
```

```css
#btnProcess3 {
  VISIBILITY: show;
  WIDTH: 150px;
  HEIGHT: 22px;
  Background-Color: #1E90FF;
  Border-Color: white;
  Color: white;
  Font-Weight: bold;
  Font-family: Verdana;
  Cursor: hand;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="btnProcess" id="btnProcess3" value="Start - Services" width="250">
```

Comment: hey i tried your code in my project, it didn't trigger the Alert function even though it tested okay in 'Run code snippet'. i'm confused

Comment: hey i just found out the solution, first the code is incorrect like you mentioned. then i need to clear the cache. thanks!